# Getting error while running jasmine test for controller with dependencies

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a controller with dependencies similar to the below code

`var app = angular.module("angularapp", ['servicemodule']);
app.controller("angCtrl",['$scope','Service1','Service2','Service3',
    function($scope,'Service1','Service2','Service3)
   {
     //controller does something
   }`

The jasmine test for the controller is similar to this

```
'describe('angCtrl', function() {
  beforeEach(module('angularapp'));


  var $controller,mockService1,mockService2,mockService3;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_,_Service1_,_Service2_,_Service3_){
    // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
    $controller = _$controller_;
    mockService1=_Service1_;
    mockService2=_Service2_;
    mockhService3=_Service3_;
    spyOn(mockService1, "getJsonData").and.returnValue("somevalue");
    spyOn(mockService2, "getJsonData").and.returnValue("somevalue");
    spyOn(mockService3, "getJsonData").and.returnValue("somevalue");

  }));

   it('header value should be 10', function() {
        var $scope = {};
        var controller = $controller('angCtrl', {
            $scope: $scope
     });
        expect($scope.header.length).toEqual(10);

    })
});'
```

When I run the Jasmine test I get an injector error followed by   TypeError: $controller is not a function.This is something related to dependency injection but i am not able to figure out the exact reason

Comment: `spyOn(mockService1, "getJsonData").and.returnValue("somevalue")` or `spyOn(mockheatService1, "getJsonData").and.returnValue("somevalue")`

Comment: edited.It is mockService1